# Is that a right place to post questions about Stable Diffusion models?

Tags: discussion

Is that a right place to post questions about Stable Diffusion models?

It's looks like it is the most relevant place in stack exchange, but I have not found tag related to Stable Diffusion. If I'm wrong, what site you can suggest?

Comment: feel free to create a new tag when asking your question: see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/tagging for guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What site you can suggest?

- https://ai.stackexchange.com
- http://datascience.stackexchange.com
- http://stats.stackexchange.com

All three SE sites mostly overlap on AI.